# Why my django signals not working for User model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-signals

I want to implement django signals on User model for create user profile. I want to create user profile when any user will be registered. here is my code for create user profile though signals:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def user_is_created_or_save(sender,instance,created,**kwargs):
         user = instance.user
         first_name = instance.first_name
         last_name = instance.last_name
         if created:
            UserProfile.objects.create(user=user)
```

I am not understanding why user profile not creating when any user registered?

**#updated question**

I am using Abstract user model. here is my user mdoel:

```
class UserManagement(AbstractUser):
      is_blog_author = models.BooleanField(default=False)
      is_editor = models.BooleanField(default=False)
      is_subscriber = models.BooleanField(default=False)
      is_customer = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Subscriber(models.Model):
      user = models.OneToOneField(UserManagement, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
      email = models.EmailField(max_length=1000) 
      first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
      last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
      is_subscriber = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class UserProfile(models.Model):
      user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="userprofile")
```

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: No Sir. I am not getting any error.

Comment: I see. Did you also create your own custom user model?

Comment: BrianD Yes I am using Abstract Model

Comment: Can you show that? It seems you need to use that model as a sender and not user from `from django.contrib.auth.models import User`

Comment: @BrianD I updated my question. please see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a custom user model has been defined, you can't use `from django.contrib.auth.models import User`. It is also not a recommended way to reference the user model.

As described in the [**`docs`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model) if you have properly setup your custom user model, you can use `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` to reference your custom user model as the sender:

```
from django.conf import settings


@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def user_is_created_or_save(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    ...
```

Comment: can you please little bit explain why User model was not working?

Comment: Sure. It's not working because you have a new custom User model (UserManagement) you have defined. So the old one (`django.contrib.auth.model.User`) is not being used anymore that's why signals are not triggering